# How to wait until page contains 1 of the two predefined elements in Selenium Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Is there a way to wait until Web page contains 1 of the two elements  in Selenium Library.

I tried the following code but clearly it does not work:

```
Wait Until Page Contains    user is registered    Or    user already existed
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use the [Wait For Condition](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20For%20Condition) keyword?

Please note that you must give it a javascript expression (in your case it suppose to be `document.body.innerText`).

Answer (score 2):

Until you find a more precise answer maybe you could try with something similar to the following:

```
${textPresence}    Run Keyword And Return Status    SeleniumLibrary.Wait Until Page Contains     hello world
Run Keyword If    '${textPresence}' == 'False'    SeleniumLibrary.Wait Until Page Contains   hello people
```

And pay attention to the keywords' timeout.